# What caused "silver eye" instead of red eye, and what can I do about it?

Tags: red-eye

I ended up taking a few flash pictures with my Nexus 5 phone with the flash. Instead of red eyes, I have robotic silver eyes. Aperture does not correct these when asked.

Is there something I did to get these unconventional reflections? Am I now in need of full photoshop or gimp to repair?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for how you got the "effect": My guess is that you were too far away for the weak flash on the phone to do anything *other* than produce the red-eye, which means the phone still had to increase the exposure (probably via high ISO) to the level required by the available light anyway, blowing out the red in the red-eye in the process.

It's not difficult to fix manually with a paint program like GIMP, just view at 2:1 (200%), and use the smallest brush available.

ADDENDUM: The reason the flash was low-power in the first place may have been because the camera was metering (at least partially) on the bright white paper the girl is holding.

Answer (score 4):

As per request of some of the higher people in the comments:

BURN THEM! (the pupils black that is, not your friends).

It doesn't that long to do in GIMP (not even 5 min):

- magic lasso the pupils
- select the burn\dodge tool
- go to town on them (just don't over burn or else they'll look evil and not robotic).